# Cosmic Inflation: Lower Expansion Rate with than without?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation

When I read the Cosmic Inflation diagram at
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Horizonte_inflacionario.svg
which I rotated to make it readable:

[Plot 1 http://yukterez.enabled.io/inflation.png](http://yukterez.enabled.io/inflation.png)

where the Hubbleradius, and therefore also the Hubbleparameter, which is c/Hubbleradius, is constant over inflation, then it seems to me, that with inflation the Hubbleparameter would have been much lower than without:

[Plot 2 http://yukterez.enabled.io/Inflation_Plot.gif](http://yukterez.enabled.io/Inflation_Plot.gif)

If the Hubble Parameter would go with Ω-Radiation (to the 4th Power), it would reach Infinity at 0, and about 10^103 m/sek/m at Planck size, which is way more than the expansion rate postulated for inflation:

[Radiation dominated Expansion Rate near 0 http://yukterez.enabled.io/Hp.PNG](http://yukterez.enabled.io/Hp.PNG)

Did I get this right, or do I have the wrong data? And if I have it right, is it more like the green curve with a hard inflation to radiation edge, or the blue one with a smooth blending; or is there all another way to get a plottable Hubble Parameter including inflation as a function of the scale factor?

PS: the
y Axis is the Hubble Parameter (c/Hubbleradius) in m/sek/m
and the
x Axis is the Scale Factor in m/m (dimensionless).